# Express Server 404ing All Requests Made From Index

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the following express/gulpfile.js code, I am having an issue with express serving the `index.html` fine but the index itself cannot hit the `lib/*` directory and just 404s all the requests made at the top of my `index.html`.

I am proxying browser-sync with nodemon. However I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with my browser-sync config because when I just use `node config/server.js` the same problem persists.

Express config:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var filePaths = require('./filePaths');
var app = express();

//filePaths.releaseIndex === './release/index.html'
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(filePaths.releaseIndex, {root: './'});
});

app.listen(5000);
```

Gulp task config:

```
//filePaths.release === './release'
//filePaths.server === './config/server.js'
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:5000",
        files: [filePaths.release],
        browser: "google chrome",
        port: 7000
    });
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
    var started = false;
    return nodemon({
        script: filePaths.server
    }).on('start', function () {
        if (!started) {
            cb();
            started = true; 
        } 
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<script src="lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
```

Folder structure:

```
config
    server.js
release
    index.html
        lib
            es6-shim.min.js
            Rx.js
            ...
```

I've tried many different variations in the `res.sendFile()` but just can't get a foothold although I am sure that it is the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have u tried using full path instead of `./relesse/index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server does not handle any other paths than `/`. To handle them you could add this after your first route:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(req.url, {root: filePaths.release})
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Express as you can tell and I appreciate you answering this one and helping me out. Cheers.